# Issue with connect to TCP/IP connections postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Can't connect to server. I have deployed a website written in Flask to Vercel (tmvr-club.vercel.app). And there I have a form for sending emails. That's when I make a POST request, it gives me that connection error. Here is my code in Flask: **app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:------@localhost:5432/vrcustdb'**. My firewall is completely disabled. I checked the server through the terminal using psql -U postgres and everything works. The postgresql.conf file has **listen_addresses = '*'** with **port = 5432** and is not commented out. In the pg_hba.conf file, it stands like this:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

but it still doesn't work. When I changed the configuration, I restarted the server, but it didn't help. I have Postgresql 14.11 and Windows 10

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything.  What's the problem you are trying to solve?  And, by the way, did you open port 5432 in the Windows firewall?

Comment: Did you check the logfiles? And what's in there? Could you share some information?

Comment: @TimRoberts I have deployed a website written in Flask to Vercel. And there I have a form for sending emails. That's when I make a POST request, it gives me that connection error. Here is my code in Flask: 

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:******@localhost/vrcustdb'

My firewall is completely disabled. I want to say I didn't open port 5432

Comment: @FrankHeikens Where i can check the logfile? I want to share some information, but tell me what you need to check and I'll show it to you

Comment: What connection error?  You didn't include the error message.

Comment: OK, but where is your Postgres database?  Your connection string says "localhost".  Are you sure Postgres running on the exact same machine that is doing the web hosting?  Most web hosting companies host their databases on other machines.